# Restart task in docker service after a certain time

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm

I have a swarm with 3 nodes. On it, I want to launch one service for a Database and then another, with some replicas that run a python application. The program will take approximately 30 minutes to finish. After that, the container is shut down and a new one starts. Sometimes, however, some problem occur and the container does not stop. Is there any option that I can use when I launch the service so that, after 1 hour, a container is automatically killed and a new one is created?

Comment: Can you create an healt check? (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) Combined with a restart policy that should do what you want

Comment: @ChristianSauer, I have never created a health check before so I am not sure what to check. Can I somehow get the time the python app has been running in the container?

Comment: An healtcheck can be anything, e.g a bash script running inside the container which checks if a certain file has been touched by your python app in the last few seconds... or whatever makes sense to indicate that your app is alife and well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an application using the Docker Remote API, that automatically creates that container, waits for one hour, deploys it to the swarm and then deletes that container. This is not a feature to look for in docker. You should manually implement it using Docker API.
You can find in [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdks/) complete list of docker libraries to help you get started.